# i want to customize my automatic download function to be unautomatic just redirect to download page

Tags: php, function

i would like to customize my function, currently, when i click download it automatically download mp3 file, but i want it just to redirect to the download page and let the user click download themselves, so i don't want it be auto download, how should i correct my code please help this is my code thank
In short, i want to close force download, this is my website you could try it, www.vox79.com
and here is my download helper code this link(http://www.vox79.com/page/35-code)

```
function download_mp3()
{
    $query              = decode(urlencode($this->input->get("q",TRUE)));   
    $data               = json_decode(searchYoutube($query));       
    $artist             = urldecode($this->input->get("a",TRUE));       
    $track              = urldecode($this->input->get("t",TRUE));   
    setDownload($artist,$track,'','mp3');           

    $videoID            = get_video_id($data);

    $video              = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$videoID;
    $download_service   = $this->config->item("download_service");              
    $download_service   = str_ireplace("%youtube_url%", $video, $download_service);
    $download_service   = str_ireplace("%youtube_video%", $videoID, $download_service);             
    if($videoID == '')
    {
        redirect("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$query",'location');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect($download_service,'location');
    }
}
```

Comment: use http_redirect() or header() as per your need.

Comment: i really appreciate your response, but i am totally new to this, could you please be more specific, where should i put the code http_redirect() or header() as per :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($videoID == '')
    {
        header('Location: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$query');
    }
```

Comment: it is still automatic download :(, www.vox79.com could you please try it, or i have to change the code somewhere else :) thank for your help

Comment: give me link of your video which is automatically download

Comment: i really want to do that but there is some problem, so i have change my website language now, could you please just search the song you want and try to click the download button at the bottom of the player, it is next to button"next song" thank you for your help :) almost all of the song are auto download :(

Comment: is it related to download helper this is my code,the code is in the link thank

Comment: i think the cause of automatic download come from this code                                      {
  redirect($download_service,'location');
}